# Dynamic Time Warping recursive implementation

Tags: python, optimization, recursion

Good evening ladies and gents,
I want to implement a Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) algorithm in Python.

For testing purposes I set up a small random distance matrix (e.g., generated by the Manhattan metric) and then call my DTW algorithm with it.

```
import numpy as np
from dynamic_time_warping import compute_dtw

x=np.zeros((3,4))
x[0,2]=1.0
x[0,3]=2.0
x[1,2]=1.0
x[1,3]=2.0
x[2,0]=1.0
x[2,1]=1.0
x[2,3]=1.0

compute_dtw(x)
```

My DTW algorithm looks as follows:

```
def compute_dtw(W):
    if W.shape[0]==1 or W.shape[1]==1:
        C=float("inf")
    if W.shape[0]==1 and W.shape[1]==1:
        C=0.0
    else:
        C=W[len(W),len(W)]+min(compute_dtw(W[0:-1, 0:-1]),
            compute_dtw(W[0:-1]), compute_dtw(W[:, 0:-1]))
    return C
```

I want the algorithm to take the m*n value of x and add it to the next minimum value which I tried to achieve by calling the function again with a smaller matrix. `(compute_dtw(W[0:-1, 0:-1]), compute_dtw(W[0:-1]), compute_dtw(W[:, 0:-1]))`

This gives me the following error after going once through the script:

> C=W[len(W),len(W)]+min(compute_dtw(W[0:-1, 0:-1]),
>   compute_dtw(W[0:-1]), compute_dtw(W[:, 0:-1])) IndexError: index 3 is
>   out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Apparently, I am calling an element of the array that's not existent, but I can't figure it out where it is breaking.

Thanks for your suggestions and help!

//updated code:

```
def compute_dtw(W):
    if W.shape[0]==1 and W.shape[1]==1:
        C=0.0
    elif W.shape[0]==1 or W.shape[1]==1:
        C=float("inf")
    else:
        C=W[W.shape[0]-1,W.shape[1]-1]+min(compute_dtw(W[0:-1, 0:-1]), compute_dtw(W[0:-1]), compute_dtw(W[:, 0:-1]))
    return C
```

Comment: Is something ever saved into the matrix `W`? It does not look so... Furthermore, the recursion in the DTW algorithm, like in many other algorithms, is implemented using Dynamic Programming, in order to avoid making redundant computations that will raise your time complexity from `O(MN)` to `O(2^N)` or even worse. Here is a Dynamic Programming implementation of DTW: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw/blob/master/simpledtw.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python indexing starts at zero.  On your first pass you calling for element [3,3] (which does not exist) and the thus the out of bounds error.

I'm not all that familiar with dynamic time warping, but I think should be using the `.shape` of the specific axis as opposed to the `len()` which is just the length of the first dimension of your array.  Even then, you'll have to adjust your recursion to iterate over the bounds of each successive array.

Lastly, the `return` statement should be at the same level of the `if` blocks.  Currently, `compute_dtw` won't return anything in the first two cases, only if the shape is greater than length 1 on both axes.

Comment: Ouch, thanks for the hints. I updated the first post. It seems to work now. Just started the run on the full data set (100 time series à 69 data points) seems to take quite a while... Would greatly appreciate it, if you could have a look at the updated code.

Comment: @Dahlai, I hope the suggestions didn't sound harsh (was not my intent). After the DTW is completed, are you expecting a "matrix" of the same dimensions that was passed in?  I think right now it will return a scalar.  Good luck.

Comment: not at all! I want to get a scalar back, which would indicate the shortest path through the distance matrix. Running the script on my data however runs forever it seems. Still some more troubleshooting to do, unfortunately.

Comment: ,Turns out I need to use dynamic programming, otherwise I'll get too many function calls. Thanks anyways for your help!